# Firewall rules baseline

Tags: networking, firewall

Is there a tool which I can use to monitor network traffic so that I can determine firewall rules and implement them on an existing network?

Comment: What type of firewall do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Well, sounds like you just need to get a good read on what sort of traffic is crossing your network. For that, set up a mirrored port on one of your switches, connect a PC to it, and fire up [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). After getting a packet capture, you'll be able to very easily see what's going on.

When doing this sort of work, I typically start from a "deny all" perspective. Assume that you're going to block everything, and then make a list of what applications need to be accessible through the firewall, and what allow rules you'll need for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a tool which I can use to monitor network traffic so that I can determine firewall rules and implement them on an existing network?*

pfSense has features that allow you to create firewall rules from invasive "bad guys", and add the rule to your firewall. This is listed under the Diagnostics menu "States". Basically if you see a threat in your logs, you can double click and add a rule to block the threat. It works the other way as well. If you are blocking a game for instance, and you want to play that game, you can unblock that rule.

Essentially a really great tool if you want to monitor your network traffic.